# Wide to long in pandas but with column values as a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to transform a dataframe from wide to long, from this one:

```
    country_code    category    statistic       2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015
0   AFG Rural   Population using at least...    22.0    22.0    23.0    23.0    24.0    25.0    26.0    27.0    27.0    28.0    29.0    30.0    31.0    31.0    32.0    33.0
1   AFG Urban   Population using at least...    31.0    31.0    33.0    35.0    37.0    38.0    40.0    42.0    44.0    46.0    47.0    49.0    51.0    53.0    55.0    56.0
2   ARG Total   Population using at least...    24.0    24.0    25.0    26.0    27.0    28.0    29.0    30.0    31.0    32.0    34.0    35.0    36.0    37.0    38.0    39.0
3   ARG Total   Population using at least...    24.0    24.0    25.0    26.0    27.0    28.0    29.0    30.0    31.0    32.0    34.0    35.0    36.0    37.0    38.0    39.0
4   COL Total   Population using at least...    24.0    24.0    25.0    26.0    27.0    28.0    29.0    30.0    31.0    32.0    34.0    35.0    36.0    37.0    38.0    39.0
```

and I need a new dataframe who has the country_code, the category, and the year as column values and the values for the statistics that are in the statistic column as new columns like this:

```
country_code  category year   Population using at least...  Population using safely...
AFG           Rural    2000   22.0                          31.0
AFG           Urban    2001   22.0                          31.0
ARG           Urban    2000   83.0                          80.0
COL           Rural    2000   75.0                          82.0
```

And I've been using melt, stack and other pandas functions and I can't get it to work.

Comment: please include the sample data  isntead of an image. Thank you!

Comment: Your data dose not look like right after you convert from wide to long

Comment: @BENY he previously posted an image, which had the multiple values in the statistic column, but in the data that he pasted in, it didn't have the additional value.

Comment: @DavidErickson row 2 and 3 are duplicated

Comment: @BENY I see what you mean. I was confused about the input data a little bit as well. I did `df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')` which pulled in the index column as `country_code` which made the multi-index unique, so that I could `unstack` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `melt` the dataframe as such, but you need to specify the `id_vars`. Then `set_index()` columns in preparation to pivot the last column from rows to columns as desired in the output. Note your sample dataframe only had one unique field for the 'statistic column' but you will see multiple columns in your actual data:

```
cols = ['country_code', 'category', 'statistic']
df = (df.melt(id_vars=cols, var_name='year', value_name='')
        .set_index(cols+['year'])
        .unstack(2)
        .reset_index())
df.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df.columns] # makes column names clean/single-level
df
Out[1]: 
    country_code   category  year  Population using at least...
0              0  AFG Rural  2000                          22.0
1              0  AFG Rural  2001                          22.0
2              0  AFG Rural  2002                          23.0
3              0  AFG Rural  2003                          23.0
4              0  AFG Rural  2004                          24.0
..           ...        ...   ...                           ...
75             4  COL Total  2011                          35.0
76             4  COL Total  2012                          36.0
77             4  COL Total  2013                          37.0
78             4  COL Total  2014                          38.0
79             4  COL Total  2015                          39.0
```

Preparation for `unstack()`. You must have 2 or more columns on the index. As you can see we have 4 below after using `set_index()`:

[image]

Then, we simply pivot the column at `index=2` from rows to columns:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was trying to do. I don't understand yet the part of unstack and how it works that set_index with that argument.

Comment: @IvanParra see the images and explanation of the two steps I posted. This has confused me in the past. The key idea is that you need to have multiple columns in the index as a prerequisite to unstacking one of them to columns. My updated answer explains better.

Comment: I'm very grateful to you. With that image everything is clear. Thank you master!

Answer (score 2):

Try with `drop_duplicated` first ,then `stack` + `unstack`

```
out = df.drop_duplicates().set_index(['country_code','category','statistic']).stack().unstack(2)
```

Comment: I finally understand the use case for `.stack().unstack(2)`. Then you would just need to use `reset_index()` and rename the column that was stacked. Thanks, a little bit easier than melting.

Comment: @BENY Amazing! Within one line! Thank you so much!